# What is accidental metaplasm & metathesis across words?

Tags: terminology, linguistics

What is accidental metaplasm & metathesis across words?

Such as...

> grammar teacher --> trammar greacher

Does this have a name?

Comment: I've no idea what an accidental metaplasm is, but I certainly know what a spoonerism is.

Comment: Note that it's still called a spoonerism whether it's accidental or deliberate. Reverend William Archibald Spooner was notorious for the accidental variety.

Answer (score 5):

This is called a [*spoonerism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism) regardless of whether it is accidental or deliberate (Wikipedia, emphasis added):

> A spoonerism is an error in speech or deliberate play on words in which corresponding consonants, vowels, or morphemes are switched (see metathesis) between two words in a phrase, for example saying “The Lord is a shoving leopard.” instead of “The Lord is a loving shepherd.” While spoonerisms are commonly heard as slips of the tongue resulting from unintentionally getting one's words in a tangle, **they can also be used intentionally** as a play on words.

Comment: The OP uses the terms metaplasm and metathesis, which sound medical to me. Is the constant use of spoonerisms, considered a  neurological dysfunction of some sort? Sounds a bit like verbal dyslexia. Does anyone know if it is a recognised condition?

Comment: @WS2: You can look up both words easily. Neither are considered medical situations but common historical phonological processes (metaplasm include metathesis).

Comment: @Mitch In the ODE (not OED) 'metaplasm' doesn't have an entry, and under 'metathesis' it simply refers to 'the transposition of sounds and letters in a word'. But one senses an underlying notion that this is an involuntary process of some kind, but no one actually mentions that.

Comment: @WS2: 'Metaplasm' is new to me, but from a dumb google search looks like it is used in rhetoric for all sorts of sound changes. Whatever the modification is, there is no connotation to the words of intention just a description of the phenomenon. Of course it is easy to infer that such changes are mistakes which are mostly unintentional, as Bradd's quote states.